# Does Postgres store by primary keys?

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I'm developing a note app. You can think it's like Evernote.
For this kind of apps, every user will only query their own data. They won't query others' data.

Let's assume the table definition

```sql
CREATE TABLE "notes" (
  id integer,
  user_id integer,
  content text,
  created_at timestamp
);
```

A user normally wants to query his latest 100 notes.

```sql
select * from notes where user_id = $my_id limit 100 order by created_at desc
```

Even though I can add `index(user_id, created_at)` or `index(user_id, id)`, if the rows from the same user are stored in separate disks, data acquisition will still be slow.

What should I do to make sure the rows from the same user are stored as close as possible?

I don't consider NoSql.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "stored in separate disks"?

Comment: Why do you think it would be slow if you have an index on `(user_id, created_at)`? Do you have an actual performance problem? If yes, then please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you preserve the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan.

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for [`CLUSTER notes USING notes_user_id_created_at_idx`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-cluster.html) but really that's an after-the-fact optimisation, nothing you should need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of three ways to try:

1. Create an index

   ```
   CREATE INDEX ON notes (user_id, created_at) INCLUDE (id);
   ```

   and query like this:

   ```
   SELECT id, created_at
   FROM notes
   WHERE user_id = $my_id
   ORDER BY created_at DESC
   LIMIT 100;
   ```

   If the table is autovacuumed often enough (lower `autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor` for the table), you will get an *index only scan* that doesn't have to fetch data from the table, so it can be fast even if the table is not clustered.

   Then you fetch the `content` for those `notes` that the user wants to inspect.

   That would be a net loss if the user wants to see the content of all 100 notes, but would win out if that is not the rule.
2. You can `CLUSTER` the table `USING` and index on `(user_id, created_at)`.

   Then PostgreSQL rewrites the table in that order, and your index scan will be fast.

   There are two disadvantages to this approach:

   - While `CLUSTER` is running, the tables is locked even to readers. So this is effectively down time.
   - The order is not maintained, but will decay as the table is modified, so you will have to repeat the `CLUSTER` run regularly.
3. List partition the table by `user_id`. You could lump several users into one partition to limit the number of partitions.

   Then you can put the individual partitions in different tablespaces on different disks.

   But it is questionable if that will give you a speed gain. Usually it is an advantage rather than a disadvantage to have data spread over several devices (striping).

   The main benefit here would be that dropping a partition is cheap, so if you have one customer per partition, it is easy to get rid of all their data at once.

Comment: Thank you a lot! Your answer is what I need. My first idea before asking is to partition the table by user_id, or even one table for one user like `create table notes_123`, but it violates some best practices.